# Build package in Yeoman

Tags: build, package, yeoman

I'm new to Yeoman and am trying to build the final package once the project is done.

I couldn't find any article or tutorial related to this. Ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more researches I found out that we just need to use a simple command: `grunt build` and that's it. Package done.